# Global error handler, getting error details

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm trying to implement a "global error handler" for my web app.

As a test, I'm running this code:

```
nope(); // this function does not exist
```

As expected, in the console I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: nope is not defined

I am trying to get access to this text via my error handler function, but both of my approaches are only providing a more generic message (Chrome 61):

```
// approach #1
window.onerror = function(message) {
  console.log(message); // "Script error."
};

// approach #2
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
  console.log(e.message); // "Script error."
});
```

Is there a better way of getting hold of the more detailed error message?
Is there a library out there for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries.  One is stacktrace.js https://www.stacktracejs.com/